# Stream.WriteTo locks up thread

Tags: c#, stream

I have this code:

```
public static void SerializeRO(Stream stream, ReplicableObject ro) {
    MemoryStream serializedObjectStream = new MemoryStream();
    Formatter.Serialize(serializedObjectStream, ro);

    MemoryStream writeStream = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(writeStream);

    bw.Write(serializedObjectStream.Length);
    serializedObjectStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    serializedObjectStream.WriteTo(writeStream);
    serializedObjectStream.Close();

    writeStream.WriteTo(stream);

    bw.Close();
}
```

The line `writeStream.WriteTo(stream);` never finishes. The program gets to that line and won't progress.

`stream` is always a `NetworkStream`. I've checked and I think it's a valid object (at least it's not `null` nor disposed).

So what's going on?

Comment: Why can't you just do Formatter.Serialize(stream, ro)? Why do you need 2 MemoryStreams?

Comment: You also need to be placing your streams in `using` blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code - writing to a `FileStream` - and I always get zero bytes written to the stream. I don't know why `WriteTo` would block on a `NextWorkStream` when there's nothing to write, but that could be a problem

When I extract the bytes from the `MemoryStream` and write them directly to stream everything works e.g. (I'm creating a binary formatter in the routine, it seems you already have a formatter).

```
public static void SerializeRO(Stream stream, object ro)
{
    MemoryStream serializedObjectStream = new MemoryStream();
    var f = new BinaryFormatter();
    f.Serialize(serializedObjectStream, ro);

    MemoryStream writeStream = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(writeStream);

    var bytes = serializedObjectStream.ToArray();
    bw.Write(bytes.Length);
    bw.Write(bytes);

    var bwBytes = writeStream.ToArray();

    stream.Write(bwBytes, 0, bwBytes.Length);

    bw.Close();
}
```

However I'd do it like this with one `MemoryStream` and writing directly to `stream`, unless there's something I don't know about `NetworkStream` (this will of course close `stream` which may not be what you want)

```
public static void SerializeRO(Stream stream, object ro)
{
    byte[] allBytes;
    using (var serializedObjectStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var f = new BinaryFormatter();
        f.Serialize(serializedObjectStream, ro);
        allBytes = serializedObjectStream.ToArray();
    }
    using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(stream))
    {
        bw.Write(allBytes.Length);
        bw.Write(allBytes);
    }
}
```

Version that won't close your NetworkStream (just don't put the binary writer in a using statement or `Close()` it)

```
public static void SerializeRO(Stream stream, object ro)
{
    byte[] allBytes;
    using (var serializedObjectStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var f = new BinaryFormatter();
        f.Serialize(serializedObjectStream, ro);
        allBytes = serializedObjectStream.ToArray();
    }
    var bw = new BinaryWriter(stream)
    bw.Write(allBytes.Length);
    bw.Write(allBytes);
}
```

Comment: Sorry just saw - and fixed - some mangled code in the first version in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just my thoughts: try to close your `BinaryWriter` before writing stream to another. While your writer is opened stream is not finished and as the result `WriteTo` newer will find the end of the stream.

Comment: Closing the binary writer closes the writeStream, indeed... But then I can't get the data out of the writeStream (because it's closed). So what do I do?